# Exception for missing data

Tags: c#, exception

I was wondering what kind of exception should one throw for missing data. For example if an xml node doesn't contain data. It would be easy to "**throw new Exception(...)**" but this is not recommended. Another option would be to create a new exception class like **MissingDataException** or **InvalidDataException** but isn't there a built-in exception class for this case?

Comment: Why throw an exception when you can return function result indicating that some data is missing?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, check the existing .NET framework exceptions for a suitable exception to throw before deriving your own. To answer your question directly, there is no "missing data" exception currently available to throw, but that doesn't mean there aren't suitable exceptions to cover your situation.

In your case, the humble [`InvalidOperationException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception.aspx) may be suitable; this exception is thrown when you call a method on an object, but the object's state is not appropriate for the operation. Examples of this include calling methods on a closed stream and an enumerator that has passed the end of the collection. If the XML data is the internal state of an object, and a method call has discovered the bad data, [`InvalidOperationException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception.aspx) is a good candidate.

If you are passing your XML data to a method, an [`ArgumentException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception.aspx), or one of its derivatives may be an appropriate choice. There is a small family of these exceptions, all indicating that an argument passed to a method is not as the method expected.

You will only want to create a custom exception when you want the exceptional circumstance to be handled differently from other exceptions. If you do choose to create your own exception, be sure to derive it from a higher exception than [`Exception`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.aspx), so that the nature of the exception is implied by the base class.

Comment: +1 I agree 100 percent, use what the system offers and only then if you can't find something that will work then create custom exceptions.

Comment: A possible candidate would also be `ValidationException`

Comment: I have to disagree with the ValidationException idea - as the documentation specifies, that is part of the System.Activities library and "...is meant be thrown when a Windows Workflow Foundation element, such as an Activity or Workflow, is in an invalid state"

Comment: The Microsoft documentation describes the above answer here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception?view=netstandard-2.0#Standard

Answer (score 20):

There is also `System.Data.ObjectNotFoundException` class which you may consider.

**Update:** As of Entity Framework 6, this exception class' fully qualified name is `System.Data.Entity.Core.ObjectNotFoundException`.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16747649/when-upgrading-from-ef5-to-ef6-should-i-replace-system-data-objects) for further details on EF5->EF6 namespace changes.

Comment: That one is part of System.Data.Entity.dll and could create an unnecessary dependency.

Comment: @Stijn Sure.That is why I said 'you may consider'.

Comment: There is no similar exception in EF Core. I had to use more generic DataException

Answer (score 8):

Do not call "throw new Exception", because you don't know how to handle the exception.

Define your own exception. Be more specific, such as XMLDataMissingException. Then you can give a meamingful message to user or log it.

Comment: Set the message with the specifics.

Comment: No, you really shouldn't be throwing a generic exception. Exceptions are meant to be handled and you may want to handle different exceptions in different ways. A generic Exception should be the last resort when you have no idea what to do when it happens. In this context, a SomethingNotFound exception would me more appropriate because you may want to try and create the missing data in your handler, which you may not want to do if there's some other exception.

Answer (score 6):

For a general missing data scenario, where the data is referenced by a unique ID, then the `KeyNotFoundException` might be appropriate - e.g.

`throw new KeyNotFoundException($"Expected record for key {key} not found.");`

It is in the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `System.Xml.XmlException`.

Edit : Even if `System.Xml.XmlException` could fit, I think you should define your own exception, as it would be more precise, and you could describe what kind of data is missing : an id, a date, etc.

Comment: System.Xml.XmlException is used by the runtime to indicate an error reading an XML document, specifically where the XML is not of the correct format (e.g. unclosed tag, missing root element). It even includes line and character numbers. Doesn't feel like a particularly good fit to me.

Comment: If his XML shall have data in a node, and haven't any, IMO the XML isn't of the correct format, so he can show at what line (even what char number if he wants). I think this fit, even if defining his own exception would be better.

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb you should throw exceptions in Exceptional Circumstances.  If the data in question adversely affects the object’s state or behaviour then throw a custom exception.  An alternative approach might involve some kind of validator that fires events which your client handles gracefully, for example, report the error to end-user or insert default values.

I had a similar problem you described in which I had 2 clients (call them A & B) reading and modifying a single xml file.  Client A deleted node X then Client B attempted to update node X.  Clearly, updating a node that no longer exists is a problem.  To solve this problem I took inspiration from SQL Server which reports the number of rows affected by an UPDATE statement.  In this particular case I raised the UpdateNode event as normal with a number of rows affected property set to zero.

Comment: You should probably define what you mean by *custom exception*

Answer (score 1):

`InvalidDataException` actually exists. It's in the `System.IO` namespace.
[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.io.invaliddataexception)

IMO, it's more appropriate than `ArgumentException` or another [boneheaded exception type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/vexing-exceptions).

Also, I strongly suggest that you use messages to describe which data is missing, what was the expected value, etc...

Answer (score -6):

throw new Exception("my message"); (or other built in Exception) is often the correct approach. The alternative is an explosion of Exception classes that may only get used once.

If new Exceptions are warranted they should be created in the context of the domain, not the problem.

Comment: Creating individual exceptions for every...single...possibility is inane. Especially if you are just logging the problem and moving on. This is the correct approach many times.