# When upgrading from EF5 to EF6 should I replace System.Data.Objects?

Tags: entity-framework

I am trying to replace EF5 with EF6
A lot of my code is giving type reference errors, 
Should I replace System.Data.Objects with System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects in my references?

[Update] Also do I replace System.Data.EntityState with System.Data.Entity.EntityState ?

Comment: ["The general rule for namespace changes is that any type in System.Data.* is moved to System.Data.Entity.Core.*. In other words, just insert Entity.Core. after System.Data."](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Updating%20Applications%20to%20use%20EF6)

Comment: It's also worth noting that EF6 is still in Alpha, meaning it's not licensed for production use.

Comment: @TiesonT. Good point. "Final RTM will be with the next version of Visual Studio (we don't have dates for that). Regardless of the RTM date we will have a release with a go-live license later this year."

Comment: @TiesonT. There are no relevant restrictions in [the license](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/license). It isn't *supported* for production use, that's different.

Comment: @hvd Sorry, the license seems to have changed since the last time I looked into EF6. This is the last thing I looked at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj680688 - "They are not intended or licensed for use in production."

Comment: @TiesonT. Interesting. The license hasn't changed, so either that page is misleading, or the license of the pre-built versions is different from the license of the source code and custom builds.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson can you put that as your answer

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A quote from [the updating guide](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Updating%20Applications%20to%20use%20EF6);

> The general rule for namespace changes is that any type in System.Data.* is moved to System.Data.Entity.Core.*. In other words, just insert Entity.Core. after System.Data.

In other words, yes, you should update your references to the new namespace.

Comment: The NuGet package for EF6 seems to have done this automatically for me (no errors).

Answer (score 19):

Yes... You should update your references as follow:

```
System.Data.Objects -> System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects
System.Data.EntityState -> System.Data.Entity.EntityState
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know why this would need to be changed in a new MVC5 project with EF6 used from the start? In other words, how or why does this happen?

Comment: Microsoft decided to reorganize the namespaces I suppose.

Answer (score 7):

One more change if you use DbGeography:

```
System.Data.Objects     =>     System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects
System.Data.EntityState    =>     System.Data.Entity.EntityState
System.Data.Spatial.DbGeography    =>   System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography
```