# After upgrading to EF6 from EF5, my generated classes do not reference the new System.Data.Entity namespaces

Tags: c#, entity-framework, upgrade

I am upgrading an existing project that was developed in VS2012 using EF5 to VS2013 using EF6.
I've gone through the steps outlined at: http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Updating%20Applications%20to%20use%20EF6

And I understand the steps outlined here: [When upgrading from EF5 to EF6 should I replace System.Data.Objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16747649/when-upgrading-from-ef5-to-ef6-should-i-replace-system-data-objects)

The problem is, the class files being generated from the ef still reference System.Data.Objects and System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.

What do I have to do to get these generated files generating properly?

Comment: how do you generate them? You need an EF6 T4 generator.

Comment: I use the model browser to visually set everything up against my db, then when I "save"/"save all" it generates the files under my model.tt. 
-Edit: So, your question (and my response) made me look at my tt files, I found the incorrect/old using statements under the ___Model.Context.tt.  If I update that file, it clears out the errors.

Comment: ok, so you used an old EF4/EF5 T4 template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was corrected in EF 6.0.2
Answering/closing