# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.EntityState' to 'System.Data.Entity.EntityState'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am getting this error in asp.net when using Entity Framework :
"Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Data.EntityState` to `System.Data.Entity.EntityState`. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Here is the snippet:

```
foreach (OrderLine line in order.OrderLines)
{
    context.Entry(line.Product).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
}
```

Please suggest what should I do to resolve the error.

Comment: What type is `context`?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

When you are using EF 6 or moving from EF 5 to EF 6, you should use `System.Data.Entity.EntityState` instead of `System.Data.EntityState`. This error happens when your project has reference to EF6 but you have code for EF5.

Also, check this link: [When upgrading from EF5 to EF6 should I replace System.Data.Objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16747649/690329).

Comment: When adding a new controller that inherits from "Web API 2 OData Controller with actions, using Entity Framework" the generated code contains   `db.Entry(application).State = EntityState.Modified` which should be changed to this `db.Entry(application).State = Entity.EntityState.Modified`

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me in a generated controller. It works for me after removing `using System.Data.EntityState` and adding `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`

Answer (score 0):

Your code must be like this:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    db.Entry(movie).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
return View(movie);
```