# cannot implicitly convert type system.data.entitystate to system.data.entity.entitystate(are you missing a cast?)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have recently done some update in visual studio and this error started happening, I am really new to MVC and I am not sure what caused this error.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using SystemInformation.BookedEvent.Interfaces;
    using SystemInformation.DBModel;

    namespace SystemInformation.BookedEvent.Repository
    {
     public class BookedEventRepository : IBookedEventRepository
        {
         public void UpdateBooking(IEnumerable<DBModel.BookedEvent> bookings)
            {
        foreach (var booking in bookings)
        {
            var record = new DBModel.BookedEvent
                             {
                                 ID = booking.ID,
                                 UserID = booking.UserID,
                                 EventID = booking.EventID,                                  
                                 DateBooked = booking.DateBooked,
                                 Trainer = booking.Trainer,
                                 Date = booking.Date,
                                 EndDate = booking.EndDate,
                                 Attended = true
                             };
             _context.Entry(record).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which line is the error point here ?

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21127553/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-system-data-entitystate-to-system-data-entity. You probably have references to an older version of EF

Comment: Try `_context.Entry(record).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;`

Comment: The error is on the line _context.Entry(record).State = EntityState.Modified; but is shown only from EntityState.Modified;

Answer (score 2):

You need

```
_context.Entry(record).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
```

insted of

```
_context.Entry(record).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

There is two entity state one in `System.Data.EntityState` and another is `System.Data.Entity.EntityState` and [`Entry.State`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696243(v=vs.113).aspx) refers to the type of `System.Data.Entity.EntityState` Which gets conflicted with what you have in namespace declarations.

Comment: after changing that line of code it still is giving the error

Comment: the error it gives is Error Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.EntityState' to 'System.Data.Entity.EntityState'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: @laura Are you sure you are having `System.Data.Entity.EntityState`? please update the question code.

Comment: I have updated the code, am i suppose to have a using statement I am missing or a reference that should be included?

Comment: @laura no nothing is required. It should work. I wonder for this behavior. Try cleaning the solution and build solution again.

Comment: @laura you are having imbalanced curly opening and closing braces. I believe it is just a type on question.

Comment: I have tried to clean and rebuild the solution but the error still exists, the code was working fine until I applied some updates in VS and there is no imbalanced braces, and only  System.Data.EntityState.Modified is highlighted in the line of _context.Entry(record).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified; of code

Comment: I have tried _context.Entry(record).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified; as @Alex mentioned, the error disappears but when I attempt to run the code a new error is generated An exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception.

Comment: @laura oh That's my typo :). my answer states it should be `System.Data.Entity.EntityState` but code snippet stated `System.Data.EntityState`... which was worng...

Comment: The other error now appears that was mentioned in my previous comment, what is causing this?

Comment: @laura It doesn't seems any error here on your code but this kind of error happens while proper connection string is not provided to _context while initializing.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have updated the EF 5 to EF 6 .

for Update record state in **EF 5  use System.Data.EntityState**
& in **EF 6 System.Data.Entity.EntityState** .

It may be possible after doing this its showing error then rebuild solution .