# What exception should I throw if a configuration value is missing?

Tags: c#, exception

I have a static class that retrieves values from app.config in its constructor. These could potentially be null, and I would like to throw an exception if this is the case.

I would like to throw the error in the static methods that use these values, but `ArgumentNullException` doesn't seem right as they are not arguments passed to the method.

Is there an alternative, or is this not a good approach?

Comment: you could create your own exception type

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453200/exception-for-missing-data

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It does not matter what you throw.  It is not an exception that should ever be caught, catching it does not fix the .config file.  Using a custom exception type only encourages a bad practice.

So don't, just throw Exception.  Be sure to tell the reader what is wrong with the .config file, that's the only thing he needs to know.  And that he *can* read it, write an event handler for AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException

Comment: There isn't going to be a reader in this case, as its a console app running on a schedule. My idea was to throw it, catch it in calling code and log the issue.

Comment: Yes, logging is always a very good practice in your UnhandledException event handler.  And trying to slog on when configuration is not correct and pretend it didn't happen, that's a very bad practice.  The mistake is easy to correct, no reason to try to get the job done anyway.

Answer (score 4):

You can create your own custom exception (MSDN).

Basically:

```
public class ConfigurationValueMissingException : Exception
{
    public ConfigurationValueMissingException()
    {
    }

    public ConfigurationValueMissingException(string message)
        : base(message)
    {
    }

    public ConfigurationValueMissingException(string message, Exception inner)
        : base(message, inner)
    {
    }
}
```

Why? If you follow Microsoft Code Analysis rules, you can't simply `throw new Exception();` as that would be a violation of [CA2201: Do not raise reserved exception types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182338.aspx):

> **Do Not Throw General Exceptions**
>
> If you throw a general exception type, such as Exception or
>   SystemException in a library or framework, it forces consumers to
>   catch all exceptions, including unknown exceptions that they do not
>   know how to handle.
>
> Instead, either throw a more derived type that already exists in the
>   framework, or create your own type that derives from Exception.
>
> **How to Fix Violations**
>
> To fix a violation of this rule, change the type of the thrown exception to a specific type that is not one of the reserved types.
>
> **When to Suppress Warnings**
>
> Do not suppress a warning from this rule.

This would be a custom exception that fully passes Code Analysis rules:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

[Serializable]
public class ConfigurationValueMissingException : Exception
{
    public ConfigurationValueMissingException()
    {
    }

    public ConfigurationValueMissingException(string message)
        : base(message)
    {
    }

    public ConfigurationValueMissingException(string message, Exception inner)
        : base(message, inner)
    {
    }

    protected ConfigurationValueMissingException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        : base(info, context)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use any of the [System.Configuration namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration(v=vs.110).aspx) exceptions. Or create your own ConfigurationParameterNullException

Answer (score 1):

Create a class that inherits from Exception:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87cdya3t(v=vs.110).aspx

```
public class NullConfigEntryException: Exception
```

And then throw a NullConfigEntryException when you find an empty one

Answer (score 0):

A custom exception is the most informative, and you have control over what information it includes.  A more generic approach is to use ApplicationException (the most generic being Exception).  If you take the generic approach, be sure to add details in Message, Data, etc.

Comment: LordJam's answer seems more appropriate to your specific situation